Sufficient conditions for a polynomial function to have the same critical points as its symmetrized version
Are there any sufficient conditions known for a polynomial function (of many variables) to have the same critical points as its symmetrized version (with respect to all variables)?
This question has naturally come up on my research, in that I have a family of functions whose critical points I have to find. I'm able to prove that the symmetrized versions of these functions all have only one critical point, and numerical simulations support the claim that the original function also has that same critical point. I would like to be able to justify this claim.
